# Trying to print from an application in PCL

Tags: printing

Trying to use a new application which has been developed for us, and runs a report in PCL to our HP LaserJet pro m404dn.

The code is below, I believe it is missing an opening thesis, but I am far from a PCL expert, the software developers are telling me its a printer issue, but I am not so sure. Code is pasted below.

```
<landscape><column|2>24/06/20 - 25/06/20<column|50>Goods Receipt Note<column|104>Page 1
<column|2>Site: Site1 <column|30>Client: Client 1<column|85>Order: PO-1075


<column|2>Pack ID<column|21>Product<column|42>Description<column|63>  Qty<column|116>  Weight<column|69>UOM<column|77>Batch<column|88>Rota<column|98>Ref3<column|107>Ref4
<push><line|1|130><pop>
<column|2>100001539<column|21>213043 - BEECASUAL<column|42>Bee Stripe Single Te<rj|68>100<rj|124>9.000<column|69>EACH<column|77>240620<column|88>24/06/20<column|98><column|107>
<column|2>100001583<column|21>213040 BEESTRPN<column|42>BEE & STRIPE OVEN GL<rj|68>724<rj|124>155.663<column|69>EACH<column|77><column|88>24/06/20<column|98><column|107>
<column|2>100001589<column|21>213040 BEESTRPN<column|42>BEE & STRIPE OVEN GL<rj|68>720<rj|124>154.644<column|69>EACH<column|77><column|88>25/06/20<column|98><column|107>
<column|2>100001590<column|21>213042 - BEESTRPG<column|42>Bee Stripe Single Ov<rj|68>604<rj|124>30.200<column|69>EACH<column|77>250620<column|88>25/06/20<column|98><column|107>
<column|2>100001591<column|21>213041 BEESTRIPN<column|42>BEE & STRIPE PAN GRA<rj|68>14<rj|124>42.000<column|69>CARTON<column|77>240620<column|88>25/06/20<column|98><column|107>
<column|2>100001592<column|21>213041 MLTSTRPE<column|42>FLORAL & STRIPE PAN <rj|68>14<rj|124>42.000<column|69>CARTON<column|77>240620<column|88>25/06/20<column|98><column|107>
<push><line|1|130><pop>
<column|2>Summary:

<column|2>Product<rj|43>Ordered<rj|54>Processed<rj|78>Weight Proc<column|55>UOM
<push><line|1|130><pop>
<column|2>213041 BEESTRIPN<rj|43>14<rj|54>14<rj|78>42.000<column|55>CARTON
<column|2>213043 - BEECASUAL<rj|43>100<rj|54>100<rj|78>9.000<column|55>EACH
<column|2>213041 MLTSTRPE<rj|43>14<rj|54>14<rj|78>42.000<column|55>CARTON
<column|2>213042 - BEESTRPG<rj|43>604<rj|54>604<rj|78>30.200<column|55>EACH
<column|2>213040 BEESTRPN<rj|43>1441<rj|54>1444<rj|78>310.307<column|55>EACH
<push><line|1|130><pop>
<column|2>End of Goods Receipt Note report
<push><line|1|130><pop>
```

Comment: That is not PCL, or PCL-XL. In fact I have no clue what it is at all, I've never seen anything quite like it. Is that exactly what you are sending to your printer ? Or is this code you've written in your application, which you then print to the printer ? If you sent that directly to a PCL printer I'd expect it to print exactly as it looks in the web page here, what do you get ?

Comment: Thanks Ken, that is exactly what prints too, I am trying to push it back to the developers but they are adamant that its our printer configuration